# Patio wall ideas

Tags: outdoor, patio, sound-proofing, design

I live in a townhouse that is near a park.  There are some days that the park is much louder than usual and once in a blue moon they play some music which has loud bass noise.

I am trying to put mass between the park and my window which faces the patio.  I obviously can't post up drywall as this would be ugly and most likely won't be approved by the building HOA.  Any ideas of nice designs that I can come up with of building a room in my patio to add mass between the park and my window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [FWHA](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/environment/noise/noise_compatible_planning/federal_approach/audible_landscape/al04.cfm) - For example,  I imagine a large triple-glazed conservatory on a solid concrete foundation would reduce the noise on the ground floor.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to cover the bass with anything you put up, short of a wall. Depending on how loud it gets the vibrations of heavy bass are deep enough to where it can be heard inside through many walls. Best bet, ask them to lower the volume/bass or call the law enforcement to have them turn it down.